# Eclipse won´t update the filesystem

Tags: java, eclipse

Im stuck on this for a few days now. Also tryed searching for an answer but only find the other way around. Is there any way eclipse will update your real files, in your filesystem on hitting save. Im working a lot with a git console or sharing files with a friend and can´t rely on eclipse, cause i have to check every time if my files are in same state as they are in eclipse.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to get Eclipse to show the files that are on your operating system, or how to get your operating system to show the files in an Eclipse project?

Comment: Also, what do you think Eclipse is updating if it's not your "real files?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does update your "real files".

It's possible you have your configuration set up wrong and your files are being saved to the workspace directory instead of the code directory. This can be checked by right clicking on a file, clicking on "Properties" and looking at the path in the "Resource" tab.

To avoid having this problem, import your projects as a new eclipse project. `File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace`

Comment: Thanks very much. I feel like a fool for not getting it.

Comment: You're welcome. Just consider it a learning experience, nothing foolish there :)